# Jade script: check if variable exists

Tags: javascript, pug, pyjade

I want to optionally pass variables to my jade template, with pyjade==4.0.0, with some JavaScript to return defined variables (to locals().pageargs):

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    console.log("#{item_id}");
```

Which works perfect when `item_id` is defined., but... how to check if `item_id` exists and if not pass `null`?

> File "/home/USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 226, in **str**
>       raise NameError("Undefined")
>   NameError: Undefined

**attempts that do not work**

```
console.log(`${'item_id' in locals()['pageargs']}`)
```

returns `False` or `True`, but:

```
console.log(`${'item_id' in locals()['pageargs'] ? locals()['pageargs']['item_id']: null}`)
```

Gives syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping it in an if-conditional, like this?

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    var item_id = !{item_id};
    if (item_id) {
        console.log(`${'item_id' in locals()['pageargs'] ? locals()['pageargs']['item_id'] : null}`);
    }
```